# How to use netcat on Mac?

Tags: mac, ipv6, netcat

I start the app with sockets on Mac and returns following:

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro niots % swift run
Building for debugging...
[2/2] Emitting module niots
Build complete! (0.30s)
Server started and listening on [IPv6]::1/::1:8888
```

Try to connect like this, it starts, but returns no response, any idea what is wrong?

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % nc -lp 8888   
rrrr
```

---

I tried also this setup:

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % nc ::1 8888
Error: Couldn't resolve host "::1"
```

This is the app, code I am checking: https://rderik.com/blog/understanding-swiftnio-by-building-a-text-modifying-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told netcat to *listen* on that port, i.e. to become a server.

Use `nc ::1 8888` if you want to *connect* to another server already listening on that port.

Comment: for that I got also an error: `Error: Couldn't resolve host "::1"`

Comment: though server is running

Comment: That sounds like macOS has an IPv4-only version of netcat? (Did it come with macOS or was installed from brew/etc?) There are probably 5 different programs all called "netcat", and *some* of them indeed do not recognize IPv6 addresses, in which case you'd have to change your server to listen on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) instead – or install a different "netcat" (e.g. netcat-openbsd or nmap's ncat) that has IPv6 support.